# How much power does a “smart meter” use?

Tags: power-consumption, power-measurement

How much electrical power does a typical domestic “smart meter” use on average, in watts, for its own operation? I have searched the internet for an answer to this question but have been unable to find one.

Comment: Probably not much. I'm pretty sure this is off topic, though. Have you looked at datasheets for individual devices?

Comment: Also... perhaps the power it uses is taken from in front of the meter, so the end user doesn't pay for it. Best to read the datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

The power used by the meter itself is called the *burden*.  The maximum value for both [ANSI](https://www.nema.org/Standards/Pages/American-National-Standard-for-Electricity-Meters-0-2-and-0-5-Accuracy-Classes.aspx) and [IEC](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/26238) meters is set at a standard maximum of 5W for just the meter. Any communications or other auxiliary devices powered by the meter or directly via the mains are not included in this.  However, modern meters and communications together typically average well under 5W.

It's probably also worth noting that the measurement is done "downstream" of the device's own power supply so the energy that a meter measures does *not* include its own use.  The result is that individual customers don't directly pay for the cost of the electricity to run the meter.  Instead, it's part of the cost of doing business for the utility.

Comment: Thank you. The term *burden* has enabled a fruitful search. For one model of meter, the burden is specified to be less than 1.5 watts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer by @Edward, searching with the term *burden* yielded a [useful link](https://smartgridawareness.org/smart-grid-information/power-consumption-and-registration-issues-for-smart-meters/) for a general discussion of this issue. In turn, the linked site provided a [link](https://skyvisionsolutions.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/elster-rex2-ea-meter.pdf) to a specification sheet where the burden of one model was rated as less than 1.5 W. The first linked site also quotes another source as saying (regarding a different meter) “The meter itself typically consumes less than 1W for most of its operating life”.

Comment: Just FYI, that first site is not generally a source of credible information.